# Migrating a django app from 1.3.1 to 1.5

Tags: django

We are considering migrating our dated django 1.3.1 app to the latest version (1.5.4).

I don't like migrations.
Are any specific problems to be thought of? Any show stoppers you may think of?
Of course I will study release notes and all this.

Will it be a real head ache or is it doable?

Comment: How about reading about backwards incompatible changes in release notes for [1.4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#backwards-incompatible-changes-in-1-4) and [1.5](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/#backwards-incompatible-changes-in-1-5) first? Or trying migration on non-production machine?

Answer (score 1):

We have migrated our app from 1.4 to 1.5, we didn't fetch any issue which is blocker. We had needed to done couple of changes related to adminmedia, json library uses and url syntaxing in our html templates. They were some normal issues only.

But yes as you said its always better to check release notes before upgrading to latest version.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the few things you need to take care of:

- Project directory structure has been changed.
- Include `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in `settings.py`.
- `django.utils.simplejson` is deprecated. `import simplejson` can be used instead.
- Session data will not be saved, when the response code is 500.
- `django.forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField` now returns an empty QuerySet as the empty value instead of an empty list.
- Uploaded files are no longer created as executable by default. If you need them to be executable change `FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS` to your needs.
- `{% load adminmedia %}` template tag can no longer be used.
- If you’re using `django.contrib.redirects`, make sure `INSTALLED_APPS` contains `django.contrib.sites`.